# Android 4.3 Device driver API Match error

Tags: android, api, cordova, match

I just started to study Android.
I made an app for simple test using PhoneGap, but the deviceready event wasn't fired.
So, I read LogCat and found some errors.

```
    02-24 21:10:18.110: D/dalvikvm(8584): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 93K, 21% free 9617K/12168K, paused 20ms, total 20ms 
    02-24 21:10:18.110: I/dalvikvm-heap(8584): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.861MB for 1127536-byte allocation 
    02-24 21:10:18.130: D/dalvikvm(8584): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 20% free 10718K/13272K, paused 18ms, total 18ms 
    02-24 21:10:18.145: I/webclipboard(8584): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4322ffe0 
    02-24 21:10:18.200: I/CordovaLog(8584): Changing log level to DEBUG(3) 
    02-24 21:10:18.200: I/CordovaLog(8584): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true 
    02-24 21:10:18.200: D/CordovaLog(8584): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true 
    02-24 21:10:18.200: I/CordovaLog(8584): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false 
    02-24 21:10:18.200: D/CordovaLog(8584): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false 
    02-24 21:10:18.205: D/JsMessageQueue(8584): Set native->JS mode to 2 
    02-24 21:10:18.210: D/DroidGap(8584): DroidGap.init() 
    02-24 21:10:18.225: D/CordovaWebView(8584): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 
    02-24 21:10:18.225: D/PluginManager(8584): init() 
    02-24 21:10:18.230: D/CordovaWebView(8584): >>> loadUrlNow() 
    02-24 21:10:18.235: D/WebView(8584): loadUrlImpl: called 
    02-24 21:10:18.235: D/DroidGap(8584): Resuming the App 
    02-24 21:10:18.285: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(8584): Ignore this event 
    02-24 21:10:18.325: V/webkit(8584): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {43227980} 
    02-24 21:10:18.335: D/webcore(8584):  CORE loadUrl: called 
    02-24 21:10:18.335: D/webkit(8584): Firewall not null 
    02-24 21:10:18.345: D/webkit(8584): euler: isUrlBlocked = false 
    02-24 21:10:18.360: D/libEGL(8584): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so 
    02-24 21:10:18.370: D/libEGL(8584): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so 
    02-24 21:10:18.450: D/libEGL(8584): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so 
    02-24 21:10:18.455: E/(8584): Device driver API match 
    02-24 21:10:18.455: E/(8584): Device driver API version: 23 
    02-24 21:10:18.455: E/(8584): User space API version: 23 
    02-24 21:10:18.455: E/(8584): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Nov 29 14:18:37 KST 2013 
    02-24 21:10:18.535: D/OpenGLRenderer(8584): Enabling debug mode 0 
    02-24 21:10:18.540: D/WebView(8584): onSizeChanged - w:720 h:1230 
    02-24 21:10:18.570: D/DroidGap(8584): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 
    02-24 21:10:18.570: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(8584): Ignore this event 
    02-24 21:10:19.005: D/CordovaLog(8584): onload event 
    02-24 21:10:19.005: D/CordovaLog(8584): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 50 : onload event 
    02-24 21:10:19.005: I/Web Console(8584): onload event:50 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: I/GATE(8584): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M> 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: D/Cordova(8584): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: D/WebView(8584): loadUrlImpl: called 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: D/webcore(8584):  CORE loadUrl: called 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: D/webkit(8584): Firewall not null 
    02-24 21:10:19.010: D/webkit(8584): euler: isUrlBlocked = false 
    02-24 21:10:19.015: D/DroidGap(8584): onMessage(onNativeReady,null) 
    02-24 21:10:19.015: D/DroidGap(8584): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: E/SQLiteLog(8584): (14) cannot open file at line 32516 of [00bb9c9ce4] 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: E/SQLiteLog(8584): (14) os_unix.c:32516: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: D/WebKit(8584): ERROR: 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: D/WebKit(8584): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: D/WebKit(8584): Cause - unable to open database file 
    02-24 21:10:19.060: D/WebKit(8584): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool) 
    02-24 21:10:21.015: D/DroidGap(8584): onMessage(spinner,stop) 
    02-24 21:10:21.050: D/TilesManager(8584): Starting TG #0, 0x4225c580 
    02-24 21:10:21.050: D/TilesManager(8584): new EGLContext from framework: 421dcb88 
    02-24 21:10:21.050: D/GLWebViewState(8584): Reinit shader 
    02-24 21:10:21.050: D/GLWebViewState(8584): Reinit transferQueue
```

I think Device driver API Match error is problem..

And here's **Manifest.xml** file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ex5"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
    <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex5.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

**index.html** File

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log("deviceready");
            alert('test');
          }
          function init() {
            console.log('onload event');
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init();">
      </body>
    </html>
```

And **MainActivity.java** File

```
    package com.example.ex5;

    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
      }
    }
```

I tested on Galaxy S3 Android Version is 4.3.
But, test on Galaxy S2 Android Version 4.0.3 worked well.

I don't know what are the problems of my sources or my Galaxy S3 Device or Android Version.

Please let me know what are the things I should fix.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem. Internet says I have the wrong Kernel (I rootet my S3) but I'm not sure about that or what to do. :(

Answer (score 0):

That error was fun! I reseted the usb keys today on my S3 and after got that error. When I tried to run my another app, the error was gone :D